# handle float value in device driver

Tags: c, linux, kernel, driver

I am writing sysfs related Linux device driver code.
I am confused about how to handle float operation on variables.
Are there any functions available to handle float operations Or Anyone knows the best way to handle float operation in a Linux kernel device driver?

I am writing a power/current/volts measurement driver which is giving output in sysfs file.

code:

```
  volts /= 27500.0;
  volts *= 250;
  volts /= 1000;
```

There are operations like this I want to handle in the kernel part, floating-point values should be accurate.

Comment: Asking about "the best way" will result in opinion-based answers and would be off-topic here. Furthermore, the terms "handle float value" or "handle float operations" are too broad. You should [edit] your question and add details about your specific problem. What exactly do you want to do with float values? What float operation(s) are you referring to? What specifically do you need help with? Adding some background information why you (think you) need float values in the device driver might also help to understand your problem.

Comment: Your example should easily be achievable with fixed point math. even a 32-bit value (16.16) should give you enough accuracy to cover mV to kV. But I guess you're working on a 64-bit platform, so even double that.

Comment: Instead of `volts /= 27500.0; volts *= 250; volts /= 1000;` do `millivolts = volts / 110;` (because 250/275000 = 1/110) and then `scnprintf(buf, PAGE_SIZE, "%d.%03u", millivolts/1000, (millivolts < 0 ? (unsigned int)(-millivolts) : (unsigned int)(millivolts)) % 1000);`.  If `volts` is never negative, then `scnprintf(buf, PAGE_SIZE, "%u.%03u", millivolts/1000, millivolts%1000);` will do fine.  (This assumes `buf` is a page, as usual with sysfs attributes.)

Answer (score 4):

The best way: Do not do it at all.

There's hardly any imaginable reason why FP operations should happen in a kernel driver. They're costly, inherently non-portable to platforms that do FP emulation, and dangerous when done wrong (you're bound to destroy the FPU context of entirely unrelated user tasks). Try to replace with fixed point math, if you can, or completely refrain from using complex math in the kernel and do it from user space.

If you think you absolutely *must* use FP in kernel functions, you might want to have a look into the `kernel_fpu_begin()` and `kernel_fpu_end()` functions (*) which save and restore the FPU context for you. Depending on the platform, these might, however, be expensive, and there's certain limitations for the possible code paths (no nesting,...). When (only) generating text output (like for sysfs) where you simply need to know where to put the decimal point, it's arguably too expensive.

(*) to my knowledge, these are only available on x86-based platforms, so you're not helping the portability of your driver.

Comment: I have to do it in the kernel only. Reson is after some division and multiplication-related operations I have to update into the sysfs.

Comment: In case you do simple division and multiplication, simply replace your FP operations with fixed-point integer math.

Comment: This is a good Idea I am thinking that only. But is there any other way or library function available to do the operations?

Comment: @chaitanyasonagara You should add all your information to the question instead of using comments for this purpose.